# EF Core to make SQL Database MERGE call and get output of new inserted record along with identify column

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, ef-core-3.1

We are using EF Core to make database call and we have a MERGE call to conditionally insert a record and what we want is once the record is inserted we want to get that new RECORD in the OUTPUT (along with the identify column). I am doing this avoid additional Select query post the insert. Following is our code, any guidance on how we can get the OUTPUT of the new record along with the identify column (auto generated value):

```
 string query = $"MERGE INTO [ReceiptMaster] AS old " +
                    $"USING (VALUES ({receipt.ProfileID},'{receipt.TranscribeID}','{receipt.ReceiptStatusID}'," +
                    $"'{receipt.ReceiptTypeID}','{receipt.TransactionDate}','{receipt.ProcessTypeID}'," +
                    $"'{receipt.TripTranscriptionVendorID}','{receipt.AcquireTypeID}',{receipt.CategoryTypeID}," +
                    $"'{receipt.IsResubmitted}','{receipt.IsResubmittedByPanel}', {receipt.ScrapeJobID}, " +
                    $"'{receipt.TripTranscriptionPayloadID}')) " +
                    $"AS new (ProfileID, TranscribeID, ReceiptStatusID, ReceiptTypeID, TransactionDate, ProcessTypeID, " +
                    $"TripTranscriptionVendorID, AcquireTypeID, CategoryTypeID, IsResubmitted, IsResubmittedByPanel, " +
                    $"ScrapeJobID, TripTranscriptionPayloadID) " +
                    $"ON new.TranscribeID = old.TranscribeID " +
                    $"WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (ProfileID, TranscribeID, ReceiptStatusID, ReceiptTypeID, " +
                    $"TransactionDate, ProcessTypeID, TripTranscriptionVendorID, AcquireTypeID, CategoryTypeID, IsResubmitted, " +
                    $"IsResubmittedByPanel, ScrapeJobID, TripTranscriptionPayloadID) VALUES (ProfileID, TranscribeID, ReceiptStatusID, " +
                    $"ReceiptTypeID, TransactionDate, ProcessTypeID, TripTranscriptionVendorID, AcquireTypeID, CategoryTypeID, " +
                    $"IsResubmitted, IsResubmittedByPanel, ScrapeJobID, TripTranscriptionPayloadID);";

            var context = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query);

            if (context == 0) return false;
            else return true;
        }
```

Comment: Use the OUTPUT clause? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you @squillman but can you help me in how I can get it to work with EF Core? As the whole output (the record) is supposed to be used in the next business logic section, any idea on how to get that OUTPUT stored in C# .net variable?